# Why in VC, both 'delete' and 'delete []' uses scalar deleting destructor?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, destructor, scalar

In my understanding for C++ memory model, only when object array is created by new[], and deleted by 'delete []', the scalar constructor/destructor are used, and compiler generates an internal for loop to iterate every element location.

```
int main()
{
    B obj;
    B* pb = new B;//no scalar constructor
    delete pb;//scalar deleting destructor
}
```

But I found when I use 'new' 'delete' to operate just one element, without using '[]', VC still generates code for 'scalar deleting descturctor' for debug version.

So my question is:

1. scalar constructor/destructor don't have to be appearing in pair, right? In my test program, I found there's only scalar deleting destructor.
2. All objects created by new or new[], should have a scalar deleting destructor? Why one element still have this consideration, I don't see any necessity for one element's case as to process exception, stack unwinding, that should rely on an extra deleting destructor. Any reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. scalar constructor/destructor don't have to be appearing in pair, right? In my test program, I found there's only scalar deleting destructor.

I could be wrong but I don't think there is anything on the constructor side that is analogous to *scalar deleting destructor*.

> 2. All objects created by `new` or `new[]`, should have a scalar deleting destructor? Why one element still have this consideration, I don't see any necessity for one element's case as to process exception, stack unwinding, that should rely on an extra deleting destructor. Any reasons?

`delete ptr` calls the *scalar deleting destructor*.
`delete [] ptr` calls the *vector deleting destructor*.

A very good answer is found at http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/scalar-deleting-destructor.1428390/.

> It's the name that's reported for a helper function that VC writes for every
>   class with a destructor. The "scalar deleting destructor" for class A is
>   roughly equivalent to:
>
> ```
> void scalar_deleting_destructor(A* pa)
> {
>    pa->~A();
>    A::operator delete(pa);
> }
> ```
>
> There's a sister function that's also generated, which is called the 'vector
>   deleting destructor'. It looks roughly like:
>
> ```
> void vector_deleting_destructor(A* pa, size_t count)
> {
>    for (size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
>       pa.~A();
>    A::operator delete[](pa);
> }
> ```